# Change UINavigationBar back button title

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, title, back-button

In my application I want to use 'Back' text as back button title for every viewcontroller.
I have read so many posts on stackoverflow but got nothing.

I don't want to set leftbarbuttonitem.

Can anyone help me on this simple task.

Thanks,

Comment: You can now set it in the storyboard.

Comment: You do realize that accepted answer has long ceased to work on modern ios? rjobidon's works

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Do this in the parent view controller not in the child

**Swift**

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

**Objetive-C**

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Comment: Tested and worlds well iOS 9.3.2

Comment: navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil) in Swift

Comment: nothing changes, I've tried `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`

Comment: have to add code above in previous view controller.

Answer (score 34):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
```

Comment: Awesome fix... Thanks

Comment: In my case `navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""` for back button

Comment: The problem with this approach would be , lets say you have a home view controller with the title "Home" , Then you navigate to the second view controller which has the title  "Child" , when you apply this , it will change the back button title , however when you go back, it will change the home screen title back button title . ;) unless you don't set it explicitly again .

Comment: This is a much better solution

Comment: it changes tittle in the middle of bar not back button's title

Answer (score 16):

If you are using storyboard you can select the navigation item in the parent view controller and set the button text you want in '**Back Button**' field. Remember to set this in the **parent** view controller, not in the child that is pushed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! this is so helpful for me

Answer (score 5):

Try this hope it will be work

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = 
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Title" 
                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                        target:nil 
                                        action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:btn];
```

Comment: add this line in view did load method from where you are switching next viewcontroller. like  you are going to detailview controller(having back button) from master view controller then add it in masterview controller viewdidload method @SeemaSharma

Answer (score 3):

I needed to use `self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"";`, the difference being that I'm using `backItem` instead of `topItem`.

Comment: It doesn't work. Where do you call it? I tried `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` but nothing happens when it calls `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "test"`

Answer (score 3):

## Back Button With Back Arrow

#### Objective-C

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = 
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
target:nil action:nil];
```

#### Swift

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = 
UIBarButtonItem(title:"Title", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```

## Normal Button Without Back Arrow

#### Objective-C

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = 
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

#### Swift

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Title", 
style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```

## Bold Button Without Back Arrow

#### Objective-C

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = 
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
```

#### Swift

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Title", 
style:.done, target:nil, action:nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Changes the currently visible Back Button

```
extension UIViewController {
func setCurrentBackButton(title: String) {
    guard let vcCount = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count else {
        return
    }

    let priorVCPosition = vcCount - 2

    guard priorVCPosition >= 0 else {
        return
    }

    self.navigationController?.viewControllers[priorVCPosition].navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you this solved a long time issue. Only one that worked.

Answer (score 1):

**swift 2.0:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
}
```

Note: It works only if storyboard have a chain of navigation stack.

Other options/changing title:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = ""
```

Removing navigationItem:

```
navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.

Comment: it changes tittle in the middle of bar not back button's title

Answer (score 1):

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove back button title for all view controller add new swift file and copy this extinction to it

```swift
    import UIKit

    extension UIViewController {
        static func swizzle(){


            let orginalSelector = #selector(viewDidLoad)
            let swizzledSelector = #selector(swizzledViewDidLoad)

            let orginalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, orginalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(swizzledViewDidLoad))

            let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(UIViewController.self, orginalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod!), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod!))

            if didAddMethod {
                class_replaceMethod(UIViewController.self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(orginalMethod!), method_getTypeEncoding(orginalMethod!))
            }else{
                method_exchangeImplementations(orginalMethod!, swizzledMethod!)
            }

        }

        @objc func swizzledViewDidLoad(){
            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            swizzledViewDidLoad()
        }


    }
```

After that in AppDelegate inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, call the swizzle function.

```
UIViewController.swizzle()
```

This function is using the objective c runtime to exchange the `viewDidLoad` method with another one that removes the back button title and then inside it recall the original `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score -3):

in `AppDelegate` in the `DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add this code:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] 
setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-1000.0, 0.0) 
forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```